# Android emulation error in windows

Tags: android, eclipse

I've downloaded the ADT bundle with the SDK, Eclipse plugin and other bits and pieces, but am having problems getting the emulator up and running. I get the following error:

> SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device

I've seen a lot of questions on SO about this error, but it only seems to come up in relation to linux users, and the questions seem to be at least a year or two old - I'm using windows (32-bit Vista). Does anyone have any experience with this error on windows, or know how I might be able to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of your virtual machine on Android SDK.
Check if the current version of Android in virtual machine is compatible with your version SDK and Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks! So I checked the version numbers installed using the SDK manager and the version I'm targeting appears to be installed - very confusing!

Comment: Try reinstall de sdk.
This error is commonly caused by: version of windows, version eclipse, version SDK or installation problem...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's taken a while for me to check and re-check everything. I've now downloaded the ADT bundle a second time and this hasn't worked, and also downloaded a base version of eclipse, installed the SDK onto windows and pointed eclipse to that, and still get the error. Is there anything else I could try?